# Trace inequality $|{\rm Tr}(ABC)| \leq {\rm Tr} (|A| |B| |C|)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, inequality, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. And we assume that **every operator in this article is self-adjoint.**

The following is well-known.

> If $A$ and $B$ are bounded linear operators on $H$, $|{\rm Tr} (A B)| \leq {\rm Tr} (|A||B|)$.

I believe that the following is also true, however I cannot prove it.

> If $A_1, \cdots, A_n$ are bounded linear operators on $H$, $|{\rm Tr}(A_1 \cdots A_n)| \leq {\rm Tr} (|A_1| \cdots |A_n|)$.

It is obvious that ${\rm Tr} (|A||B|) \geq 0$, because ${\rm Tr}(|A||B|) = {\rm Tr}(|B|^{\frac{1}{2}} |A| |B|^{\frac{1}{2}}) \geq 0$.
However, I cannot even prove that ${\rm Tr} (|A_1| \cdots |A_n|) \geq 0$.

Comment: Your last inequality is, as you suspected, no true. Take $H=\mathbb R^2$, $n=3$, and $A_i(v):=(u_i,v) u_i$, where $u_i$ ($i=1,2,3$) are vertices of an equilateral triangle centered at the origin.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it. @user8268